# Database not included in Azure Web Sites backup

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am using the [preview] Backup service to perform a daily backup of an Azure Web Site into a storage account in a different Azure region.  The backup is working as expected, except that the SQL database linked to the web site is not getting backed up (everything else is there).

I've checked that the connection string is correctly configured and have ticked the database in the dropdown list on the backup configuration page.  There are no clues in the Azure log:

```
Message:
Creating temp folder.
Retrieve site meta-data.
Backing up the databases.
Backing up site content...
Uploading metadata to the blob.
Uploading backup content to the blob.
Backup completed! Total backup size: 4750 KB
```

The only give away, perhaps, is that there is only one dot after "Backing up the databases", whereas there are three after "Backing up site content".

I'd welcome any clues on how to debug this.

Thanks,  Nick.

Comment: Have you looked at the operations log in the settings page in the portal.

Comment: Yes - the operations log says "completed successfully" and no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is correct and it is a bug in the backup feature. Sorry for the inconvenience. We discovered this internally already and the bug will be fixed in the production soon (with the next upgrade of Azure Web Sites). As a workaround for backing up your databases, please use the manual backup option.

Thanks,
Petr